# Were Stranger Things' 1st and 4th season plotlines mapped out together?

Tags: stranger-things

In the fourth season of Stranger Things, we gain new insights into what happened at Hawkins Lab to trigger the events seen in the first season, including the violence surrounding Eleven's escape, creation of "the gate", and the identity and true nature of

> Vecna/One

Was all of this developed as the first season was being written or was it "ret-conned" afterwards as the writers needed to build a story for the 4th season?

Comment: Almost always, the answer to these kinds of question is, *no*, that very little of the origin story was part of the original conception.

Comment: Stranger Things was initially a miniseries - just what became a 1st series of overgrown thing... So, the answer is **no**.

Comment: Assuming season 4's narrative wasn't conceived when writing season 1, I'm not sure it quite counts as [retroactive continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroactive_continuity). A lot of the point of season one was that Eleven and events at the Hawkins lab were mysterious; so season 4 seems like it's more filling in details than amending anything established.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite As I saw it, there were at least a couple of ways writing could have gone... one is that the writers mapped out all the major plot points about Eleven, Hawkins lab, the Upside Down, etc. to be distributed over a multi-season arc. Another is that season 1 was written as a self-contained arc with some built-in mystery and an ambiguous/ominous ending just to leave the door open for future seasons, with  subsequent season arcs progressively chained as green-lit for production. I ask because the overall narrative (as of about S3) feels like it lacks the cohesion of a pre-defined arc.